# React Navigation after login navigate problem

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I'm using useNavigation in React Navigation. After logging in with AsyncStorage, I want to redirect to the home page, but I cannot go back to the App function. When I want to go to HomePage, Navigate cannot find it and returns an error.

**How can I trigger a function named app?**

Navigate Error (console)

> The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"HomeScreen"} was not
> handled by any navigator

Login Code

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(data.data));
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  const [signedIn, setSignedIn] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    _checkUser();
  }, []);

  async function _checkUser(){
    let responseUser = await AsyncStorage.getItem("userData");
    setSignedIn(responseUser);
  }

  if(signedIn != null) {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={_homeScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={_welcomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={_registerScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={_loginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ForgotScreen" component={_forgotScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="EmailCodeScreen" component={_emailCodeScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }
}
```

When I try to do it with MOBX..

```
let signedIn = userStore.isLogin;

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
        {
          signedIn ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={_homeScreen} />
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={_welcomeScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={_registerScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={_loginScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="ForgotScreen" component={_forgotScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="EmailCodeScreen" component={_emailCodeScreen} />
            </>
          )
        }
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
```

Router

```
let data = await axios.post(baseURL+"users_checkMail", sendData);
uaStore.userStore.userData = data.data;
uaStore.userStore.isLogin = true;
await AsyncStorage.setItem("userData", JSON.stringify(data.data));
console.log(userStore.isLogin); // LOG: TRUE
setLoader(false);
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mobx for state management, create and manage signedIn state in your mobx state tree. when user logs in , you just have to set signedIn state to true. When user logs out, set signedIn to false. No need to use navigation props. When you change your signedIn state, react-navigation component will rerender.

Comment: Actually, I tried this at first, but in this case Navigation does not repeat and I keep getting the same error. I have added to the main topic so you can view it.

Comment: After logging in, I can make a change in the code section (both ways) and login when the application is reloaded.

Comment: I think your mobx implementation is not working properly. I did it in my project like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66168612/3733048

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

> It's important to note that when using such a setup, you **don't need to manually navigate** to the `Home` screen by calling `navigation.navigate('Home')` or any other method. **React Navigation will automatically navigate to the correct screen** when `isSigned` in changes - `Home` screen when `isSignedIn` becomes `true`, and to `SignIn` screen when `isSignedIn` becomes `false`. You'll get an error if you attempt to navigate manually.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/

So just remove the line:

```js
navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
```

And replace it with:

```js
setSignedIn(true)
```

Or the MobX equivalent if you use MobX.

Comment: This solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna trigger the App.js after successfull login ... then **You need to wrap your NavigationContainer with [React.Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)**

Your `signedIn` user is an `object` I think ... not an array
so by initalizing it in state with `[]` ... `if(signedIn != null)` will never evaluate to `true` ++ Make sure you `JSON.parse` your object after fetching it from `AsyncStorage` ...

```
 const AuthContext = React.createContext({
    signedIn,
    _checkUser: () => {},
  });
  
  export const useAuth = () => React.useContext(AuthContext);

  const defaultValue = {
    signedIn,
    _checkUser,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={defaultValue}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          {signedIn ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={_homeScreen} />
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={_welcomeScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={_registerScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={_loginScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="ForgotScreen" component={_forgotScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="EmailCodeScreen"
                component={_emailCodeScreen}
              />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

In LoginScreen

```
// Then you refresh you auth user in LoginScreen like
  const { _checkUser } = useAuth();
  _checkUser();
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I was doing it the longer way. Unfortunately, this is not the solution to my problem.

Comment: ... because...??

Comment: Because I still get the same error, I am filling AsyncStorage, but I cannot switch to HomePage navigation because I cannot trigger the App function again. I keep getting the same error.

Comment: If you wanna trigger the whole navigation-tree per-login ... then you have to use React Context

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {signedIn != null ? (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="HomeScreen" component={_homeScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      ) : (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Stack.Screen name="WelcomeScreen" component={_welcomeScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="RegisterScreen" component={_registerScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="LoginScreen" component={_loginScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="ForgotScreen" component={_forgotScreen} />
          <Stack.Screen name="EmailCodeScreen" component={_emailCodeScreen} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      )}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I was doing it the longer way. Unfortunately, this is not the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cant use NavigationContainer twice..I would suggest make two Navigator like this one Login and another AppStack like this! I would just use redux and redux persist with async storage,makes life easier

```
const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true});
    }, 1000);
  }, []);

const LoginStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Login"
        component={Login}
        options={{
          headerTransparent: true,

          cardStyle: {backgroundColor: colors.BACKGROUND},
          ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS,
          headerTitleStyle: {color: 'transparent'},
        }}
      />
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Terms"
        component={Terms}
        options={{
          headerTransparent: true,

          cardStyle: {backgroundColor: colors.BACKGROUND},
          ...TransitionPresets.ModalPresentationIOS,
          headerTitleStyle: {color: 'transparent'},
        }}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      {screens.map((screen, i) => (
        <Stack.Screen
          name={screen.name}
          component={screen.screenname}
          key={i}
          options={{
            headerTransparent: true,

            cardStyle: {backgroundColor: colors.BACKGROUND},
            ...TransitionPresets.ModalSlideFromBottomIOS,
            headerTitleStyle: {color: 'transparent'},
          }}
        />
      ))}
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
    
  const AppState = () => {
    const checkLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.AuthReducer.loggedIn);
    return <>{checkLoggedIn === false ? <LoginStack /> : <AppStack />}</>;
  };
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <AppState />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

store.js

```
import {applyMiddleware, createStore} from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {persistStore, persistReducer} from 'redux-persist';

import rootReducer from './index';

// Middleware: Redux Persist Config
const persistConfig = {
  // Root
  key: 'root',
  // Storage Method (React Native)
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  // Whitelist (Save Specific Reducers)
  whitelist: ['StickerReducer', 'AuthReducer'],
  // Blacklist (Don't Save Specific Reducers)
  blacklist: [''],
};
// Middleware: Redux Persist Persisted Reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));

// Middleware: Redux Persist Persister
let persistor = persistStore(store);
// Exports
export {store, persistor};
```

Auth Reducer

```
import {ADD_DEVICE_TOEKN, LOGGED_IN} from './types';

const initialState = {
  loggedIn: false,
  user_Id: '',
  device_token: '',
};

export default AuthReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGGED_IN:
      const paylodLoggedIn = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        loggedIn: paylodLoggedIn.loggedIn,
        user_Id: paylodLoggedIn.loggedIn,
      };
    case ADD_DEVICE_TOEKN:
      const paylodToken = action.payload;
      return {
        ...state,
        device_token: paylodToken,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';
import StickerReducer from './StickerReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  AuthReducer: AuthReducer,
  StickerReducer: StickerReducer,
});
```

Authaction.js

```
import {LOGGED_IN} from '../types';

export const LoginAction = (userData) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGGED_IN,
      payload: userData,
    });
  };
};
```

Finally login dispacther

```
import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
import {LoginAction} from '../../../redux/actions/LoginAction';
const Login = ({navigation}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
 return (
<Pressable onPress={() =>dispatch(LoginAction(data))}>
  </Pressable>
    );
    };
```

Comment: I've never worked with Redux before, I'm using Mobx inside. In Redux, you used the storage part AsyncStorage. In this case, when the application is closed and opened, does the data come to the automatic Store? @Mohammad Sadman

Comment: Yes Redux Persist saves the data for you..So if you logged in you are always logged in..in store js there is whitlist what reducer you want to save in storage..i have missed combine reducer i will add it...if you do like this you wont get a flick of white screen which you get in only async storage..

Comment: Wow, then instead of using a store in the app, even the smallest thing I register in AsyncStore is permanent. (Unless I erase)

Comment: Yes if you dont want save that particular reducer dont whitlist it.. I would suggest you go this way if app is big

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to use the useNavigation hook... I was able to resolve it using the dispatch method...

```
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.navigate({ name: 'Profile', params: { user: 'jane' }})
);
```

I created a utility function for less repetition...

```js
const handleNavigate = (key: string) => {
  navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate({ name: key }));
};

// Usage
handleNavigate("Home")
```

This got rid of the error for me. Hope this helps