# React Native ( React Navigation ) Authentication Flow

Tags: react-native, authentication, react-navigation

I am trying to implement a react navigation authentication flow where there are total three screens and two screen of them are in Authentication ( Login Screen and Registration Screen ) which are used to authenticate a user and the other one is Home Screen ( Feed Screen ) which shows the application's home.

Authenication Screens are in a stack navigator which is AuhenticationNavigation and the home screen is in the HomeScreenNav stack navigator. I have these two stack navigator which are used to navigate.
As in the Code Snippet.

The logic I want to implement is that after successful login the screen should navigate to Feed Screen and in Feed Screen I have a logout function which is used to logout and change the persistent state which is isLoggedIn to know that a user is logged in or not.

```js
const RootStack = createStackNavigator();

class AuthenticationNavigation extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <RootStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
        <RootStack.Screen name='Login' component={Login}/>
        <RootStack.Screen name='Register' component={Register} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreenNav extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <RootStack.Navigator headerMode='none'>
          <RootStack.Screen name='Feed' component={HomeScreen} />
      </RootStack.Navigator>
    );
  }
}
```

Two ways I tried to resolve it:
1 :-

```js
<NavigationContainer>
            { this.state.isLoggedIn ? (
              <HomeScreenNav />
            ) : (
              <AuthenticationNavigation />
            ) }
</NavigationContainer>
```

Above Code snippet shows me Feed Screen is the isLoggedIn is true and evaluates to Authentication Screen is the it is false.
But what if I want to navigate to the Auth Screens after a successfull logout in Feed Screen.
I have also the tried the react navigation authentication flow from navigation docs but I am not able to resolve my error.

2:-

```js
<NavigationContainer>
        <RootStack.Navigator
          initialRouteName={ (this.state.isLoggedIn == true) ? 'Home' : 'Auth' }
          headerMode='none'
          >
           <RootStack.Screen 
            name='Home'
            component={HomeScreenNav}
            />
          <RootStack.Screen 
            name='Auth'
            component={AuthenticationNavigation}
            />
        </RootStack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

In this way I am unable to open the Home Screen when isLoggedIn evaluates to true and it shows me Auth screen. I think that the problem is in isLoggedIn state but again I checked whether the state is really working or not properly and it resloved into a successful evaluation. But still it is evaluating as false.

Here is the process of retrieving the state which is isLoggedIn.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tokenId: '',
      isLoggedIn: false,
    }
  }

componentDidMount = async () => {
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
    this.setState({tokenId: token});
    this.setState({isLoggedIn: !Object.is(this.state.tokenId, null)});
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', this.state.isLoggedIn ? 'Y' : 'N');
    console.log(this.state.tokenId, this.state.isLoggedIn);
}
```

Request: Please provide a proper solution not any documentation links because I have searched for this problem many times on many platforms.

Comment: You need to share your state with React Context. try this solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66168612/3733048

Comment: @Erdenezaya Thanks for the help. It really helped me.